# Binary data to Number with endianess convert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-data, memory-address, endianness, arraybuffer

I received Binary Data as String, and how do I convert it to JS Number with little endian CPU? Does ArrayBuffer, DataView useful?

It is not just **radix converting question**.

**16 in 2 radix is 10000 not 10000000**

But I have to converting with memory address and get the number value.

```js
var binary = "10000000"; // 16

parseInt("10000000", 2) // 128

// Buffer 10 00 00 00
// Little Endian 00 00 00 10
// 0x00000010 => 16
```

This is answer with lodash manually. But I wanna know JavaScript ways with ArrayBuffer and DataView.

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
var endianness = null;

(function () {
    var b = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var a = new Uint32Array(b);
    var c = new Uint8Array(b);
    a[0] = 0xdeadbeef;
    if (c[0] === 0xef) {
        return endianness = 'LE';
    } else if (c[0] === 0xde) {
        return endianness = 'BE';
    }
    throw new Error('Unknown endianness');
})();

function toInt(binStr) {
    if (binStr % 2 !== 0) {
        throw new Error('Invalid binary string');
    }

    var arr = _.chunk(binStr, 2);

    if (endianness === 'LE') {
        arr = arr.reverse();
    }

    var converted = _.flatten(arr).join('');

    return parseInt(converted, 16);
}
```

Thanks you for support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works (for 32-bit values):

```
var toInt = function(binStr) {
  var int  = parseInt(binStr, 16);
  var view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));

  view.setUint32(0, int, endianness === 'LE');
  return view.getUint32(0, false);
};

console.log( toInt('10000000') );
```